# MatterJS remove object function

Tags: javascript, arrays, matter.js

I'm working with matter.js on a small project, trying to add and remove objects from a matterjs world with js functions.

the add function seems to work,
the remove method only works inside the adding function-

```
var boxes = [];

function addCircle(Cid, Ccolor, Cradius) {
    boxes[Cid] =  Bodies.circle((w/2), (h/2), Cradius, {
            density: 0.0005,
            frictionAir: 0.06,
            restitution: 0.3,
            friction: 0.01,
            render: { fillStyle: Ccolor, strokeStyle: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            lineWidth: 0,
         }
        });
    boxes[Cid].angle = Math.random() * 0.5;
    boxes[Cid].force.y -= 0.0001;
    World.add(engine.world, boxes[Cid]);
    //World.remove(engine.world, boxes[Cid]);  <-- This one works
}


function removeCircle(Cid) {
    //console.log(boxes[Cid]);
    World.remove(engine.world, boxes[Cid]); // <-- This one doesn't
}
```

console shows error "Cannot read property 'type' of undefined" for the remove function.
Can someone tell me how to solve this? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

To remove a body from a world you need to use `Composite.remove(...)`.

So in your case it'll be:

```
Composite.remove(engine.world, boxes[Cid]);
```